# Performance issues with single table hierarchy

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, database-performance

I have a lot of products with the same properties. I mean all products need the same information to be stored in database. The only difference is that some products are spare parts for other ones.

I'm thinking about making a single table with an ID for ever product. Also a ParentID field to store it's parent id. I'm thinking if this way is better? or having two tabled and join them?

Which solution has a better performance?

Comment: What are your two options? 1 Table with a self join or 2 tables, with identical column layouts? If so, go with 1 table. Also, read [this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) article on storing hierarchical data.

Comment: So if you are sure, why you don't post it as an answer?

Comment: can you specify you table structure to understand you question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using nested set, here is a good explanation :)

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/